# Google Map text style appears different on Android than in the Styling Wizard

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-styling

I created a Google Maps style in the styling wizard (https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) that does not produce the same result in my Android app as it appears in the wizard. The text labels appear bulky as if they have a large weight.

Here is the json copied from the Styling Wizard into my app:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      },
      {
        "weight": 0.1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#474644"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#626061"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
   "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#626061"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#666666"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is how the map appears in the Styling Wizard:
[image: Google Styling Wizard]

and here is the result in my Android app:
[image: Android styled map]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding stylers to my json in my Android app that sets the visibility of all label text fills to `off`

```
{
     "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
     "stylers": [
       {
         "visibility": "off"
        }
     ]
}
```